# Iframe Like button not firing edge.create

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like

I dont want to use xfbml. I need to use iframe like button like below. But that's not firing `edge.create`.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
// initalize your Facebook App
  FB.init({
    appId  : '113869198637480',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });
// subscribe to the event
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  alert('you liked this');
});
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(response) {
  alert('you unliked this');
});
</script>

<iframe id="test" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php? 
       href=http://google.com/&amp;
       layout=button_count&amp;
       show_faces=false&amp;
       width=50&amp;
       action=like&amp;
       colorscheme=light&amp;
       height=21" 
       scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
       style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px;  
              height:21px;" 
       allowTransparency="true">
```

Comment: Not, it’s __not__ possible using the iframe version.

Comment: yes, don´t use the iframe version ;)

Comment: You must use xfbml. Period.

Answer (score 8):

This is completely expected; the javascript callbacks are only available when using the Javascript version of the social plugins, including the Like Button.

This is mentioned in the [Like Button documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

```
How do I know when a user clicks a Like button?

If you are using the XFBML version of the button, you can subscribe to the 'edge.create' event through FB.Event.subscribe.
```

When you include the Like button as an iFrame directly, there's no way for the event from Facebook's servers to be propagated back to your javascript code - the Facebook Javascript SDK handles this communication when using the XFBML version of the Like button

Comment: Thanks, I know that, I still need a way (even ugly and hacky) to detect iFrame like buttons

Comment: That's not possible unfortunately

Comment: If you can get the exact coordinates (x,y) of the like button you might get the client mouse click coordinates and assume it is a Like click.